# Extract BigQuery to Newline Delimited JSON without escaping strings

Tags: json, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a BQ table when one of the columns contains an unstructured json string:
[image]

I am trying to make a BQ export job that will output this table as a newline delimited json. However, the unstructured json string is being escaped:

```
{"actor": {"id": "85", "info": "{}"}, "action": "delete"}
{"actor": {"id": "85", "info": "{\"name\":\"Terraform API key\"}"}, "action": "edit"}
```

Is it possible to export this column as a json, instead of an escaped string? This is what I would really like to get, so a simple json load method will work on each line separately:

```
{"actor": {"id": "85", "info": {}}, "action": "delete"}
{"actor": {"id": "85", "info": {"name":"Terraform API key"}}, "action": "edit"}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use JSON_EXTRACT [1]. This extracts a JSON value, such as an array or object, or a JSON scalar value, such as a string, number, or boolean. If a JSON key uses invalid JSONPath characters, then you can escape those characters using single quotes and brackets.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract

Comment: Tried that already, the example in the screenshot above is with using `JSON_EXTRACT`. That works good when making a query, or when exporting as CSV, but when exporting as JSON the export job considers this cell to be a string and not a json

Comment: Try this ````replace(to_json_string(column),'\\"','"' )````

Comment: You can try `JSON_QUERY` or `TO_JSON_STRING` functions[1].
[1]https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-json-extract/